# Is there a way to print without whitespaces at the beginning in py3?

Tags: python-3.x

Im having trouble with the output. I have to print the sum of two integers. But the output always comes with a default whitespace before the integer. How do I make it right?

'''

```
i = 4
d = 4.0
s = 'HackerRank '
# Declare second integer, double, and String variables.
# Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.
e= int(input(' '))
g= float(input(' '))
h= str(input(' '))
# Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line.

p=i+e
print(p,end='\n')
# Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.
f=d+g
print(f)
# Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line
j= str(s)+str(h)
print(j)
# The 's' variable above should be printed first.
```

'''
OUTPUT:

```
   6
7.0
HackerRank hi
```

What do I do to remove the whitespace before the integer '6'

Answer (score 1):

when you make this change you will see it clearly.

```
e= int(input(' '))
g= float(input(' '))
h= str(input(' '))
```

change to:

```
e= int(input('Enter e:'))
g= float(input('Enter g:'))
h= str(input('Enter h:'))
```

Comment: I changed it. The output is : Enter e:Enter g:Enter h:16